# Google maps draw rounded rectangles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used Google V3 to draw a rectangle on the map, but now I want to change it into rectangle plus a rounded rectangle.
I think Google's official document API contains rectangles, prototypes, polygons, lines, but now I need to add a round angle to the current rectangle. How should I do it?

```
   var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle( {
            strokeColor : '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity : 0.8,
            strokeWeight : 0,
            fillColor : '#575757',
            fillOpacity : 0.35,
            map : map,
            bounds : new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    minusXY(pointO.y, h), minusXY(pointO.x, d * 6)),//C
                    new google.maps.LatLng(minusXY(pointO.y, h * 3),
                            plusXY(pointO.x, d * 6))//D
            )

        });
```

Comment: Make it a Polygon and generate the points to round the "corners" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I use raphael to draw the graphics I need on the map.

`graph.rPaper.image('assets/module/singleUserQuery/img/topo.png', nx-80, ny-50,100,80))`